# Cannot connect Java ap to online MySQL database - wrong URL

Tags: java, mysql, url, jdbc, database-connection

I have developed a Java application and want to connect it to an online MySQL database, hosted by `db4free.net`. But I cannot achieve to get a connection through JDBC and I know that something is wrong with the URL I use. The URL that I see in my browser is :

```
https://db4free.net/phpMyAdmin/index.php?db=DB_NAME&target=db_structure.php&token=8d68285c6950611a4f9630dc2c132b61
```

This is how I read the properties :

```
public class ReadProperties {
    private String db_user;
    private String db_password;
    private String db_connection;
    private Connection connection;

    public ReadProperties(String filename){
        Properties propfile = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(filename);
            propfile.load(input);

            db_user = propfile.getProperty("db_user");
            db_password = propfile.getProperty("db_password");
            db_connection = propfile.getProperty("db_connection");

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection( db_connection, db_user, db_password);
            System.out.println(connection);

        } catch (IOException | SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my properties file :

```
db_user=USERNAME
db_password=PASSWORD
db_driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db_connection=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net/DB_NAME
```

***What URL exactly should I use?*** This is what I see in phpMyAdmin (I have erased the database's name) :

[image]

Comment: did you ping your database?

Comment: can you change the name of domain to the real @IP

Comment: @LAIDANIYoucef I pinged the domain's name and it has IP `85.10.205.173`.

Comment: Maybe you should ask db4free.net how to access the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First of all you should to get the IP address and the port of your
  database :
- Second ping your database if it work then every thing will be fine like this:

[image: ping]

- The port by default is 3306 for MySQL so your URL or db_connection should look like this :

change your URL to :

```
db_connection=jdbc:mysql://85.10.205.173/DB_NAME
```

- make sure you call `Class.forName(driver);`

**EDIT**

I already create a database in this site and i create a simple program and it work with me:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class CreerConnection {

    static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static String DB_username = "youcef";
    static String DB_password = "youcef";
    static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://85.10.205.173/bd_test";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);
            System.out.println("Success");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception : " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use my data hope this can help you.

Comment: and why it work for me? try to use this @IP i already get it in my PC

Comment: @Marievi i create a simple program for you it work fine with me

Comment: @Marievi i think you forgot the `Driver class` just copie passt my program and test it

Comment: You don't need to specify default port (3306) , see https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L2219

Comment: yes you are true @rkosegi, but the program work fine, why this down-vote?

Comment: @LAIDANIYoucef did it, doesn't work. I have used the same code I posted some months before for another online database (which now does not exist) without using the `Driver class` and it worked. Something must be wrong with the URL.

Comment: @Marievi you said before that **Ping to the domain does not work.** so i assume that you have a problem with your network, because if you can't ping then you can't connect so try again with the @IP `ping 85.10.205.173` if not work you should to check your connect

Comment: @Marievi you are welcome check and tell me what you get ok

Comment: ICMP ping timeout doesn't mean that service is not available. Instead use tool like `telnet host port` which operates on TCP.

Answer (score -2):

the database is listening on a specific port and you must specify it, it should be 3306 (as i see it on the bottom of your screenshot).

Your db connection property should be :

```
db_connection=jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/DB_NAME
```

Comment: What about `phpMyAdmin` and the rest of the link?

Comment: You don't need to specify default port (3306) , see https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/ConnectionImpl.java#L2219